# How to parse these operations through lists?

Tags: python, algorithm

**Program description:**

> Program accepts a list `l` containing other lists. Output `l` where lists with length greater than 3 will be changed accordingly: the element with index `3` is going to be a sum of removed elements (from third to the end).

**My solution:**

```
l = [[1,2], [3,4,4,3,1], [4,1,4,5]]
s = 0
for i in range(len(l)-1):
  if len(l[i]) > 3:
      for j in range(3,len(l[i])-1):
        s += l[i][j]
        l[i].remove(l[i][j])
      l[i].insert(len(l[i]),s)
l
```

**Test:**

```
Input: [[1,2], [3,4,4,3,1], [4,1,4,5]]
Expected Output: [[1, 2], [3, 4, 8], [4, 1, 9]]
```

**Program run:**

```
Input: [[1,2], [3,4,4,3,1], [4,1,4,5]]
Output: [[1, 2], [4, 4, 3, 1, 3], [4, 1, 4, 5]]
```

**Question:** I don't understand what can be the source of the problem in this case, why should it add some additional numbers to the end, instead of summ. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: `l = [li[:2] + [sum(li[2:])] if len(li)>2 else li for li in l]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove` is the wrong function. You should use `del` instead. Read the documentation to understand why.

And another bug you have is that you do not reset `s`. It should be set to `0` in the outer for loop.

But you're making it too complicated. I think it's better to show how you can do it really easy.

```
for e in l:              # No need for range. Just iterate over each element
    if len(e) > 3:
        e[2]=sum(e[2:])  # Sum all the elements
        del(e[3:])       # And remove
```

Or if you want it as a list comprehension that creates a new list and does not alter the old:

```
[e[0:2] + [sum(e[2:])] if len(e)>3 else e for e in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `remove()` is the wrong method, as it deletes by **value**, not index:

> Python list method remove() searches for the given element in the list
> and removes the first matching element.

You'd want to use `del` or `pop()`.

Second of all, you're not slicing all of the elements from the end of the list, but only one value.

Answer (score 1):

`remove` is reason why your code is not working. (as mentioned by Mat-KH in the other answer)

You can use list comprehension and lambda function to make it a two liner.

```py
func = lambda x: x if len(x) < 3 else x[:2] + [sum(x[2:])]
l = [func(x) for x in l]
```